# Sequences with intervals

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to play a bit with sequences & intervals and I've got a few questions which I'm not sure about:

Let $a_n$ be a sequence and $I=(a,b)$ interval such that {$a_n|n\in N$} densed in $I$
I mean that for any $x,y \in I$ such that $x < y$ there is $n$ such that $x<a_n<y$

A) Based on this is it safe to say that any $L \in I$ is a partial limit of $a_ n$? because i can always find a subsequence which converges to that L am I right?
B) If {$a_n|n\in N$} then I can surely say that $b= \sup \lim a_n$? because it is not possible that any $a_n$ will pass $b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Yes, but you need to be a little careful about how you prove it. Consider the case when $a_n$ hits $L$ only once on $a_0$ and then never returns to L itself. To establish the subsequence that converges to $L$ you can't take smaller and smaller $(x,y)$ around $L$ - even though it seems natural - because then the same $a_0$ will satisfy the denseness and you won't get a growing subsequence. You need to keep taking smaller and smaller $(x,y)$ very close to, but just outside $L$.

B) You garbled the question a little and it's not clear what you're asking, but if you meant to say that $a_n$ stays within $(a,b)$, then yes, in such a case $b = \limsup a_n$ (lim sup, not sup lim) for the same reason as A).